# array.filter gives a undefined value

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, filter, fetch

I have a json file with this structure:

```
{"year" : 1990, "fact": "Er waren oorspronkelijk maar drie seizoenen van de serie voorzien"}
```

On my website, I have episodes from a movie. They all have a release date. If the release date matches with the specific year in the JSON file, I want to show a fact that belongs to that year. I try to do that with this code:

```
const showFact = async () => {
        const year = document.querySelector(`.date`).textContent.split(` `)[2];
        const response = await fetch(`./assets/data/nice-to-know.json`);
        const facts = response.json();
        const fact = facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year).fact;
        document.querySelector(`.fact`).textContent = fact;
      }
```

If I `console.log(fact)` , I see that the fact is `undefined`

Comment: `facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year).fact` so you have an array with a `fact` property? Maybe you meant `facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year)[0].fact`?

Comment: filter still returns an array, what you are looking for is `.find`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes! See the JSON file for the structure.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD I edited my comment, maybe it's mare clear now.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes I missed that, now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` still returns an array, what you are looking for is `Array.protoype.find` instead

```js
const facts = [
  {"year" : 1990, "fact": "1990 fact"},
  {"year" : 1991, "fact": "1991 fact"},
  {"year" : 1992, "fact": "1992 fact"},
  {"year" : 1993, "fact": "1993 fact"}
]
const fact = facts.find(fact => fact.year === 1990).fact;
console.log(fact);
```

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD this is the correct answer and should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, your problem is with

```
const fact = facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year).fact;
```

Because `filter` returns an array, which, of course, doesn't have a `fact` property.

Assuming `filter` returns a non-empty, single-element array, you probably meant.

```
const fact = facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year)[0].fact;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const showFact = async () => {
    const year = document.querySelector(`.date`).textContent.split(` `)[2];
    const response = await fetch(`./assets/data/nice-to-know.json`);
    const facts = await response.json();
    const fact = facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year)[0].fact;
    document.querySelector(`.fact`).textContent = fact;
  }
```

array.filter returns an array. I just had to select the first item of that array.

Answer (score 0):

As [Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca) pointed in the comments, you're trying to access a property on an array. When you filter `facts` it becomes an array, you need to map it.

```js
const showFact = async () => {
        const year = document.querySelector(`.date`).textContent.split(` `)[2];
        const response = await fetch(`./assets/data/nice-to-know.json`);
        const facts = response.json();
        const factList = facts.filter(fact => fact.year == year).map(fact => fact.fact);
        document.querySelector(`.fact`).textContent = factList.join("<br>");
      }
```

above I used `map`function to extract the facts to an array of only facts (without year), and then joined with a line break.